# React Native ScrollView event on visible element

Tags: events, scrollview, react-native

I'm working with **ScrollView** component on my app. This **ScrollView** has some **View** containers in it.

What I'd like to achieve is to fire an event (for that specific View), or something when the **View** is visible on the screen, so I can know what **View** is visible to the user at that moment.

I hope this schema helps to understand it better:

[image]

In this case, the visible **View** is the one with **ref="2"** so I'd like to fire something like **event(2)**. And when you keep scrolling and **View ref="3"** is visible, fire **event(3)**.

I don't know if this is possible to achieve, so I'd like your help :)

Comment: Still not available? :P

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible. But peeking through https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=scrolly&type=Code we can see that at least in android the emitted scroll event has a `scrollY` value. So it may be possible someday.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/03d7c7a6a1257d15c26e61cd660fb57222b5b969/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/scroll/ScrollEvent.java#L43

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have some doubts. What is **scrollX** for? What I want to control is when an element is visible to the user in the ScrollView vertically, so I don't get it why I'd need a **scrollX** event. So, there is no way to get some event to be fire when a element is visible in the ScrollView??

Comment: Not afaik. scrollX is the way we typically do this on the web. And react native is trying to match the web apis as closely as possible. So they may implement it in the future. http://devdocs.io/dom/window/scrollx you would inspect the value of scrollX in the `scroll` event and then perform logic based on what view should be visible.

Comment: scrollY rather. for the distance scrolled vertically.